# How to redirect subdomains to a specific url structure via cpanel

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, dns, cpanel

I need to redirect all subdomains of subdomain.mydomain.com to a specific url structure.

Example:

http://books.subdomain.mydomain.com should be redirected to 
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/things/books

I have created a zone file record via Advanced DNS Zone Editor:

*.subdomain.mydomain.com. 14400 IN A 178.143.78.89

but when I try to access books.subdomain.mydomain.com, it is redirected to

books.subdomain.mydomain.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Help! Thanks :)